# customizing latex table row and font color

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I have created a table in `Rmarkdown` using the following code:

```
\begin{tblr}{
row{odd} = {bg=azure8},
row{1} = {bg=azure3, fg=white, font=\sffamily},
}
Number  &  Model \\
Model 1 &  \(BC\_WS = \beta _0 + \beta _1\cdot {M\_WS} + \epsilon\) \\
Model 2 &  \(BC\_WS = \beta _0 + f(M\_WS) + \epsilon\) \\
Model 3 &  \(BC\_WS = \beta _0 + \beta _1\cdot W\_WS+ \beta _2\cdot W\_Direction+  \beta _3\cdot Temperature + \beta _4\cdot Pressure  + \epsilon\) \\
Model 4 &  \(BC\_WS = \beta _0 + f(M\_WS)+  f(W\_Direction)+ f(Temperature) + f(Pressure)  + \epsilon\) \\
Model 5 &  \(BC\_WS =\beta _0 + \beta _1\cdot (M\_WS)+  f(W\_Direction)+ f(Temperature) + f(Pressure)  + \epsilon\) \\
Model 6 &  \(BC\_WS = \beta _0 + \beta _1\cdot M\_U+ \beta _2\cdot M\_V+  \beta _3\cdot Temperature + \beta _4\cdot Pressure  + \epsilon\) \\
Model 7 &  \(BC\_WS = \beta _0 + f(M\_U)+ f(M\_V)+ f(Temperature) + f(Pressure)  + \epsilon\)
\end{tblr}
```

and the output looks like this:
[image]

How can I customise it so that it results in the following picture? I need to change the colour of rows so that rows and font colour corresponding to model 1, model 3, and model 6 be the same,  rows and font colour corresponding to model 2, model 4, and model 7 be the same and
row 5 background colour to be different. There should be aline separting two column and The second column in the first row is centred, so the output is like this:
[image]

Comment: Can you provide here what you have tried so far? Please Don't just ask "I need to do this, do that". Instead, provide here what you have tried and where did you get stuck. See this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/629943/261065 to know how to color rows of `tabularray`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you use this table, please

- note that you shouldn't use math mode for multi-letter words, all the kerning is completely broken...
- read http://betterposters.blogspot.com/2012/08/the-data-prison.html and https://texdoc.org/serve/booktabs/0 to get some idea how professional looking tables look like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{
  colspec={l|[white]l},
  cell{1}{2}={halign=c},
  rows={bg=lightgray},
  row{1}={bg=brown!80,fg=white,font=\bfseries},
  row{2}={bg=brown!80!black,fg=white},
  row{4}={bg=brown!80!black,fg=white},
  row{6}={bg=brown!80!green,fg=white},
  row{7}={bg=brown!80!black,fg=white},
}
Number  &  Model \\
\hline[white,wd=1pt]
Model 1 &  \(BC\_WS = \beta _0 + \beta _1\cdot {M\_WS} + \epsilon\) \\
Model 2 &  \(BC\_WS = \beta _0 + f(M\_WS) + \epsilon\) \\
Model 3 &  \(BC\_WS = \beta _0 + \beta _1\cdot W\_WS+ \beta _2\cdot W\_Direction+  \beta _3\cdot Temperature + \beta _4\cdot Pressure  + \epsilon\) \\
Model 4 &  \(BC\_WS = \beta _0 + f(M\_WS)+  f(W\_Direction)+ f(Temperature) + f(Pressure)  + \epsilon\) \\
Model 5 &  \(BC\_WS =\beta _0 + \beta _1\cdot (M\_WS)+  f(W\_Direction)+ f(Temperature) + f(Pressure)  + \epsilon\) \\
Model 6 &  \(BC\_WS = \beta _0 + \beta _1\cdot M\_U+ \beta _2\cdot M\_V+  \beta _3\cdot Temperature + \beta _4\cdot Pressure  + \epsilon\) \\
Model 7 &  \(BC\_WS = \beta _0 + f(M\_U)+ f(M\_V)+ f(Temperature) + f(Pressure)  + \epsilon\)
\end{tblr}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "you shouldn't use math mode for multi-letter words"? Can you mention exactly what part of my code it refers to? Regarding your links, I think I have to change the table to look like the third one in one of the references (betterposters) you sent to look more professional. I will post a new question then. because I will need such a table when reporting the output of my statistical tests

Comment: The comment about not abusing math mode is basically about your whole code. Have a look at e.g. how `Temperature` is rendered in your code. The space between T and e is way to big, while the space between p and e is much too small. You can use `\text{Temperature}` from the amsmath package to avoid the problem

Comment: Great, Are there any references for choosing colours in case I want to change them?

Comment: Don't change the background colours, that add too much noise. Theoretically you could change the text colour of some rows to show they belong together, but that's also risky in case some of your readers are colour blind and/or print in black/white. A safer option would be to add a small extra column with symbols which group the rows, e.g. a small star or diamond ....